# replace text according to a line number and a columns range

Tags: awk, sed

In a text file `foo.txt`:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
sed quam rutrum, interdum sodales ex
pellentesque urna placerat
```

I want to replace text on **line 2** from **column 10 to 16** with another string "fermentum", resulting in:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
sed quam fermentum, interdum sodales ex
pellentesque urna placerat
```

Precision : regex Is a NO to catch `rutrum` need index positions

Comment: Is it the 3rd word you need to replace or position 10-16. Does the word always have 6 characters?  Why not regex?  I did gave you `-1` since its not clear what the goal is and you have not posted what you have tried.

Comment: @Jotne it is clear : "I want to replace text on line 2 from column 10 to 16". Question seems to be clear enough to already have 4 great answers :)

Comment: If the line was just som random characters using location should be clear, but here you tries to change a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way how to use `sed` to substitute text exactly in the line 2  starting from column 10(inclusively) to 16(exclusively).

```sh
sed -E '2s/^(.{9})(.{5})(.*)$/\1fermentum\3/' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

`-E` is used to avoid escaping parentheses and similar...

`2` means - exactly in the second line

`s` means `substitute`

`^` - beginning of the line

`(.{9})` captures 9 any single characters (`'sed quam '` in this particular case)

`(.{5})` captures next 5 characters (`'rutrum'`)

`(.*)` captures zero or more remaining characters (`', interdum sodales ex'`)

`$` - end of line

`\1` - reference to the first captured text

`\3` - reference to the third captured text

`> bar.txt` is responsible for storing the result in `bar.txt`

More details can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm).

Comment: smart and elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

```
[C]$ cat foo.txt | ./line2-col10_16.sed
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
sed quam fermentum, interdum sodales ex
pellentesque urna placerat

[C]$ cat foo.txt | ./line2-col10_16.sed > new 
[C]$ diff foo.txt new 
2c2
< sed quam rutrum, interdum sodales ex
---
> sed quam fermentum, interdum sodales ex
[C]$ cat line2-col10_16.sed
```

```
#! /bin/sed -f
#
# cat foo.txt | ./line2-col10_16.sed
#
# foo.txt:
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
# sed quam rutrum, interdum sodales ex
# pellentesque urna placerat
#
# I want to replace text on line 2 from column 10 to 16 with another string "fermentum", resulting in:
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
# sed quam fermentum, interdum sodales ex
# pellentesque urna placerat
#
# sed
#
# line 2
# substitue 
# LHS match 3 groups
# \1: any char 9 times
# \2: any char 6 times
# \3: everything else
# RHS replace with
# group 1 + "fermentum" + group 3
2 s/^\(.\{9\}\)\(.\{6\}\)\(.*\)/\1fermentum\3/
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite easy in `awk` using `sub`. You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `awk` works. (other than with the GNU awk `FIELDWIDTHS` extension), `awk` does not act on characters, it acts on *fields* designated as being delimited by the `FS` (field-separator, default - whitespace). So to operate on `"rutrum,"` you would want to operated on the 3<sup>rd</sup> *field* in the 2<sup>nd</sup> record. You can identify the second line using `FNR == 2` (file record number) or `NR` for the (record number) of all files being processed.

The `awk` solution to your case would be:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {sub(/^rutrum/,"fermentum",$3)}1' file
```

Where `sub(/find_regex/,"replace"[,target])` designates the optional target as the 3<sup>rd</sup> *field*.

**Example Use/Output**

With your original text in `file` you would get:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 2 {sub(/^rutrum/,"fermentum",$3)}1' file
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
sed quam fermentum, interdum sodales ex
pellentesque urna placerat
```

**Edit - Using only Line and Column Numbers**

If you cannot use regular expressions and can only use the line number and column number, then you can still use `awk` with `substr` and string concatenation. Essentially you will just build the 2<sup>nd</sup> line from the first 9-characters of the line plus `"fermentum"` plus characters 16 on, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {s=substr($0,1,9); s=s "fermentum"; s=s substr($0,16); $0=s}1' file
```

Above each of the 3-pieces are concatenated in the string `s` and then the 2<sup>nd</sup> line is set equal to the new concatenated string. (output is the same as above)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. unfortunately I can't use regex at all in my case : only line and columns index poaitions

Comment: Ok, you can still use `substr`, I'll drop another edit.